# Can't get Google Event Tracking to work with Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, events, analytics

I am trying to count the clicks on the Facebook like button in a modal popup.

There seems to be a problem in this part of the code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/smartmommypagina/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'likebox', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'like' });"></div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? It has been hours already. Thanks.

Comment: No we can't. Because you have not told us what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, forget the spaces.

Comment: Look at the HTML code. That div will be replaces with different HTML code that has the like button. Just adding onClick will not help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean I can't put the onClick in there like this because it's Javascript?

Comment: I mean because there will be no click on that div so having onClick there doesn't do anything

Comment: I see, thanks. Any idea how I can get this thing to work? You might know another topic where this is explained to a rookie?

Answer (score 1):

That is what event subscriptions are for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

`edge.create` and `edge.remove` would be the events for the like button, there is example code in the docs.